# he generado la autenticacion de usuarios de laravel la "auth" y tiene una vista reset.blade.php que no me deja cambiar los estilos

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

a que se debe que en esta vista no pueda cambiar los estilos, que esta fallando?

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('body-class', 'login-page sidebar-collapse')

@section('content')
<div class="page-header header-filter" style="background-image: url('img/bg7.jpg'); background-size: cover; background-position: center center;">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Reset Password') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('password.update') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <input type="hidden" name="token" value="{{ $token }}">

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="email" value="{{ $email ?? old('email') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="password" required>

                                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Confirm Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Reset Password') }}
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@include('includes.footer')
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: ¿Has comprobado que aparezca el atributo style en la vista que te envía Laravel? ¿Has probado a añadir !important?

Comment: ¿Seguro que son solo los estilos?

Comment: si son solo estilos como ese div con la imagen no se carga

Comment: recien probe añadir !important y no paso nada

Comment: estoy en resources/views/auth/passwords/reset.blade.php y no me modifica ni un estilo :(

Comment: ¿Estás intentando modificar la vista del enlace al que te lleva el link de "Forgot Your Password?" verdad? ¿Cual es la ruta hacia esa vista?

Comment: estoy usando laragon esta es la ruta -->https://shopp-app.test/password/reset

Comment: con el https://

Comment: pero usando el comando php artisan serve tampoco se aplican los cambios uso laravel 5.7

Comment: No estoy editando la vista equivocada ni tampoco es un problema de cache ayuda @Shaz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si no me equivoco, el problema está en que estás editando la vista equivocada.

La vista que está en `auth/reset.blade.php` es la vista cuando haces click en el enlace que te llega al correo para resetear la contraseña.

La vista para el formulario es `auth/email.blade.php`

Comment: no lo que esta pasando es que ninguna de las vistas autogeneradas de la carpeta passwords estan pudiendo ser editadas en cuanto al css ni la reset,blade.php ni la email.blade.php y no se porque ni se como arreglarlo

Comment: no se que pasa?

Comment: dices que no es auth/passwords/reset.blade.php sino solo auth/reset.blade.php ? porque yo tengo las vistas en una carpeta llamada passwords

Comment: no puedo cambiar los estilos, ni siquiera puedo pasar el texto a español porque la vista no cambia

Comment: Lo que quiero decir, es que suele haber confusion entre la vista del email y la del formulario de recuperar contraseña. Si estás intentando cambiar la vista del formulario, se llama email.blade.php. Aunque si me dices donde como llamas a esa vista podemos avanzar mas rapido